# Snakemake: Combine different rules for all files in a certain directory

Tags: snakemake

Recently, I started using snakemake for data analysis.
I am still a beginner, and this is my first post on stackoverflow.

I have different rules that produce different output, but all should run on all files of a certain directory.

Here is a simplified example:

```
LABELS, = glob_wildcards('{label}.dat')

rule all:
  input:
    expand('{label}-A.out', label=LABELS),
    expand('{label}-B.out', label=LABELS)

rule A:
  input: expand('{label}-A.out', label=LABELS)

rule B:
  input: expand('{label}-B.out', label=LABELS)

rule create_A_out:
  output:
    '{label}-A.out'
  shell:
    'touch {output}'

rule create_B_out:
  input:
    'test.dat'
  output:
    '{label}-B.out'
  shell:
    'touch {output}'
```

To update all output files at once, do I have to write a rule like 'all' that manually collects all output files that I need?

Or is there a way to combine rules 'A' and 'B' (and more rules), so that I can easily run all at once?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not positive on your question, but as written the rules A and B are superfluous.  If you want to directly link rule outputs, you can use [rule dependencies](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#rule-dependencies), though I prefer to have the file names left explicit.  Perhaps you are looking for a more complex expand, such as this:

```
LABELS, = glob_wildcards('{label}.dat')
analyses = ['A', 'B']  # ...

rule all:
  input:
    expand('{label}-{analysis}.out',
           label=LABELS,
           analysis=analyses)

rule create_A_out:
  input:
    '{label}.dat'
  output:
    '{label}-A.out'
  shell:
    'touch {output}'

rule create_B_out:
  input:
    '{label}.dat'
  output:
    '{label}-B.out'
  shell:
    'touch {output}'
```

By default, `expand` will produce the combination of all lists you supply.  I also added wildcards to your inputs and added inputs for the .dat file you are globbing against.  If you are keeping the same general format, just add a rule and an element to analyses.

If you have tons of analyses to do, you can also get fancier with [anonymous rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#rules).  Say I have python scripts, `analysis-[A-Z].py`.  You can link those to an output file like so:

```
LABELS, = glob_wildcards('{label}.dat')
analyses = ['A', 'B', ..., 'Z']

rule all:
  input:
    expand('{label}-{analysis}.out',
           label=LABELS,
           analysis=analyses)

for analysis in analyses:
   rule:
       input: '{label}.dat'
       output: f'{{label}}-{analysis}.dat'  # will be {label}-A.dat after formatting
       script: f'analysis-{analysis}.py'
```

You could even make analyses a dict with shell scripts as the values, but that would be really hard to follow!

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful answer! All of these tricks are useful to me. Concerning the rule dependencies, I realized that I can also link rule inputs.

Comment: Previously, I used the first suggested solution. Recently, I tried out the second suggested solution (with anonymous rules). While the output of the rules is assigned correctly, the rule that should call the script `analysis-A.py` instead calls `analysis-B.py`. It seems that `{analysis}` is replaced by the value of the variable `analysis` at runtime, which is then `B`. Now, I found a workaround. If a parameter is defined `params: this_analysis = analysis`, it can be used for the script `script: f'analysis-{{params.this_analysis}}.py'`. Via this workaround, the correct script is called.

Comment: Since the suggested edit queue is full, I cannot edit the answer directly. Therefore, I typed the correction in a comment for future reference.

Comment: Just for completeness, there are also two minor typos concerning the output, which should be `out` files instead of `dat` files. So, the line should read `output: f'{{label}}-{analysis}.out'  # will be {label}-A.out after formatting`. Of course, none of these issues takes away that this was a very helpful answer!