# How to make a nested loop in Snakemake?

Tags: shell, nested-loops, snakemake

I need to make a nested loop in snakemake, so far I've tried different ways but nothing worked.

This is part of the snakefile I'm working on. I am not sure this is the right way of doing it, because I get an error.

Does anyone know the right way of doing this in snakemake?

````
STEPSMSA=["0","10","20","30","40","50","100","150","200","300","400","500","600"]
LENGTHS=["30","35","40","45","50","55","60","65","75","85","100","150","200","400"]

rule all:
    input: expand("simulations/gen_{steps}_n1000000_l200.fa",steps=STEPSMSA)

# run fragSim
for p in STEPSMSA:
    for l in LENGTHS:
        rule:
            input: "simulations/gen_{param}.fa".format(param=p)
            output: "simulations/gen_{param}_n1000000_l{l}.fa".format(param=p)
            shell: "/home/incerta/jana/Software/gargammel/src/fragSim  -n 1000000 -l {l} {input} |gzip > {output}"```
````

Comment: _I get an error_  is not an entirely helpful problem description. Could you be a bit more specific here?

Comment: ```MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce Snakefile_new (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).```   This is what I get.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably, three errors.

First, based the error message, I assume that you try to use a new
snakefile called `Snakefile_new` (instead of the usual name
`Snakefile`). You can do so using the option `-s`, e.g.,

```
snakemake -j 1 -s Snakefile_new
```

Second, the format of `{l}` is missing in the output.

Third, there maybe problems with which values of `p` and `l` are used in
the shell of an anonymous rule. [I recently had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64500405/13995159) and found that a snakemake parameter defined in `params` led to the right definition of the rules.

The following soultion should hopefully work:

```
STEPSMSA=["0","10","20","30","40","50","100","150","200","300","400","500","600"]
LENGTHS=["30","35","40","45","50","55","60","65","75","85","100","150","200","400"]

rule all:
    input: expand("simulations/gen_{steps}_n1000000_l200.fa",steps=STEPSMSA)

# run fragSim
for p in STEPSMSA:
    for l in LENGTHS:
        rule:
            input: f"simulations/gen_{p}.fa"
            output: f"simulations/gen_{p}_n1000000_l{l}.fa"
            params: length = l
            shell: f"/home/incerta/jana/Software/gargammel/src/fragSim  -n 1000000 -l {{params.length}} {{input}} |gzip > {{output}}"
```

Note that the solution uses [f-strings of python3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/).